# video4linux not working in new kernel (new kernel is not creating /dev/video0)

Tags: linux-kernel, video, v4l

I am using an HDMI to USB capture device that linux sets up as /dev/video0.  It works like a webcam, but captures from HDMI.  It works perfect using the vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic kernel.  After updating to the vmlinuz-5.0.0-47-generic kernel, v4l2 does not set up the /dev/video device.  After rebooting to the vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic kernel, the device works perfectly again.
Hardware info:
The computer is an ASUS M4A88T-M motherboard with no other pci cards installed, running linux Mint 19.3, 64-bit.

With new kernel (vmlinuz-5.0.0-47-generic) v4l2-ctl --all shows...

```
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

With the older kernel (vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic) v4l2-ctl --all shows...

```
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : UVC Camera (534d:2109): USB Vid
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:12.2-4
    Driver version: 5.0.21
    Capabilities  : 0x84A00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps   : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1920/1080
    Pixel Format      : 'MJPG'
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 4147200
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-128 max=127 step=1 default=-11 value=-11
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=148 value=148
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=180 value=180
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-128 max=127 step=1 default=0 value=0
```

Is there some way to get it working (modprobe or something) in the new kernel?

As a workaround, I can set up my PC to boot the the older kernel, but is this a problem a developer would be interested in knowing so that it could be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another PC with the same OS running the 5.3.0-28 kernel and the problem is resolved.